# Regex differentiate between all vs few char Uppercase in String

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have to pass a string into a program, depending on the string, it will return only one response value. I am facing difficulty in building patterns for two cases.

- If a string ends with '?' and is **not all uppercase** return 'x', no matter what the contents of string.
- If a string end with '?' and is **all uppercase** return 'y'.
- If a string ends with '!' , or **is all uppercase** (no question mark at end) return 'z'.
- If a string is only whitespace return 'a'.

Here are two example strings, they are to be four separate patterns -

```
phrase1 = "Simple String with some UPPercase in Between ends with?"
phrase2 = "BIG STRING ALL CAPS ENDS WITH?" 
phrase3_a = "ALLCAPSSTRING NOTHING AT THE END OF STRING" 
phrase3_b = "Any String with ALL UPPERCASE (or not) but ends with!"
phrase4 = "\t\t\t\t"
```

I haven't built accurate patterns, and that's what I'm asking here. After that I plan to use a single `re.compile` with all patterns & then `finditer` to use the group which is not None. In code below, I have removed the `whitespaces`,since if none of the other patterns match,  matching a whitespace pattern `[\s]` will return None, which I can use separetely-

```
phrase=re.sub(r'[\s]','',phrase)

pattern_phrase1 = re.compile (r'[a-zA-Z0-9]\?$')
pattern_phrase2 = re.compile (r'[A-Z0-9]\?$')    
pattern_phrase3 = re.compile (r'[A-Z]|[.!$]')
```

Comment: This looks pretty close. Be sure to use `+` and/or `*` to indicate how many of those character classes you plan to match, rather than just one. But, what exactly is the question here?

Comment: @BlackVegetable I'm asking for the patterns themselves.

Comment: This type of simple conditions do not require the use of regular expressions. Used if/else statements for your checks instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 - using isx functions

```
    def hey(phrase):
        responses ={'ques':x,'ques_yell':y,'yell':z,'onlycall':b,'what':c}
        phrase=''.join(phrase.split())

        if phrase=='':
            return responses['onlycall']

        if phrase.isupper():
            if phrase[-1]=='?':
                return responses['ques_yell']
            return responses['yell']
        elif not phrase.isupper():
            if phrase[-1]=='?':
                return responses['ques']
        return responses['what']
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your issue. Consider the pattern of `if phrase.isupper()` instead of `if (phrase.isupper() == True)` and `elif not phrase.isupper()` etc. Just a pro-tip.

Comment: Also, you can accept your own answer to keep the site a tiny bit more organized. You won't gain +2 rep from doing so though.

Comment: Thank you for not answering the question straight away. I didn't know about isupper iswhitespace fxns. I also learned a lot of REGEX and do have a regex based solution which I will post. Thanks for the edits, I know it could be done that way, but sometimes i like to write more for more readability.

Comment: Fair enough. The "pythonic" way to do it is what I wrote, but I've never been overly pedantic about that anyway. I just wanted to make sure you were aware of the option.